# extracting raster pixels by 8 near neighbor values

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out a way to extract vegetation canopy cover data using python 2.6 to exclude all zero values with all 8 neighbors having zero values.  All pixels have a value ranging from 0-100 in percent canopy cover.  I figured I could do an IF/THEN statement and only extract pixels where at least one neighbor is greater than zero, but I am very new to python and don't even know where to start with scripting for the neighbors.

The reason behind this is to write a script that will automatically identify long vegetation corridors for assessment, like roads, rivers, powerlines, etc (all of which should have at least some zero values.  But also exclude large open fields (which also have zero values) because they are no good for my biological assessment.

thanks for your help

Comment: take a look at the ndimage module in scipy. Thee morphological operations are what you need. As soon as I have some time I will explain better